# MAC Layer Retransmissions during the same TXOP

Tags: wireless, protocol-theory, mac

Back in the day I was messing around with MadWifi and, if I remember properly, after a packet was transmitted if the sender did not receive an ACK in SIFS time after the completion of the transmission, the sender would attempt a retransmission using the same or lower rate (multi rate retransmissions) without going into the backoff/contention phase.

I spent some time going through the 802.11-2012 protocol trying to find relevant information without any luck. Is anyone familiar with that concept? Is this what the protocol implies?

Any pointers/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!